# Adding an active css class to navigation with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Hi All I'm looking for a simple unobtrusive way to add a class="active" to an unordered list menu based on the directory it's in. Unfortunately I can't add a custom class to the body tag so I'm unable to use a pure css solution.

Can anyone point me to a good tutorial - I've looked but can't find one that fit's my needs. Code looks like this, I just need to add the class based on /directory/ or / a jquery solution would be ideal as I'm already loading the jQuery library.

```
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/about/about.html">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="/cv/submit-your-cv.html">Submit CV</a></li>
<li><a href="/vacancies/index.html">Vacancies</a></li>
<li><a href="/news/news.html">Company News</a></li>
<li><a href="/praise/praise.html">Praise</a></li>
<li class="nosep"><a href="/contact/contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".nav li:has(a[href$='"+window.location.pathname+"'])").addClass("active");
```

Comment: Hi Nick, this is great but it seems to fail for the index page? Any thoughts on making that work?

Comment: the problem seems to be that the active class doesn't appear when the user accesses / rather than /index.html in addition if any other page is called index.html the script duplicates the active class.

Comment: @toomanyairmiles - Is making the URLs absolute an option, or do you know what the full path will be?

Comment: I can put absolute urls in some of the menus, but some of the sections are blogs and they need to inherit the class from their root directory.

Comment: @toomanyairmiles - If your site is at the root, then you can just take out `$=` and replace with `=`, changing from "ends with" to a plan equals, see if that does what you want...without knowing your layout I can't say exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the window.location variable and set an id to each li-element. Then something like:

```
$("...").addClass("myCssClass");
```

Hope it helps in some way...

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you the concept will have an output
on change color on each particular page

var wo = window.location.pathname;

jQuery("ul.nav li a").each(function(){
  var thisvar = jQuery(this);
  var ifid = jQuery(this).attr("href");

```
if(ifid == wo){

         switch(ifid){
          case "/index.html":
            thisvar.css("color","#000000");
          break;
          case "/about/about.html":
           thisvar.css("color","#EE2E24");
          break;

}
```

}
});

if you like this post you can also visit it on http://linesforme.blogspot.com